# Is this a Swift bug?

Tags: objective-c, swift, memory, memory-management

**TL;DR : Initialising data from a plist file makes my Swift app "leak" memory.**

I am building an app in Swift, to test it with data, I made a plist file and initialised an `NSArray` with it, like that :

```
 NSArray(contentsOfFile: myFile)!
```

I would then get elements of this array, so NSDictionary, NSString... of course I would typecast those, like that :

```
if let dataDic = element as? [String:Any] { ... }
```

But even by doing that, I think it's still NSArray under the hood right ?

So, my issue is that while the amount of data my algorithm was treating did NOT augment (it was always two arrays of the same size) the memory consumption of my app did !

After checking my code several times, I used Instruments to inspect my code. Using the Allocation instruments, I found some wired types that din't seemed to be really *Swifty*... : CFString, CFDictionnary and other types like those.

Here is a sample screenshot :
[image]

As you can see in this screenshot, the responsible caller is `[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:...]`

That made me think about the fact that I was initialising my data from a plist file, working with non-Swift code.
**I decided to generate data without using this plist file, and now, problem is gone ! But what can cause this ? Shouldn't Objective-C types and their Swift counterparts be interchangeable ? Did I missed something or is this a Swift bug ?**

Thank you.

EDIT : I can post code examples if needed

Comment: 1. There is no leak in your Instruments screenshot. 2. All Apple frameworks are written in Objective-C/C so if Obj-C classes appear in allocations, in means absolutely nothing.

Comment: @Sulthan I'm not saying this is fundamentally wrong to have Objective-C in allocations, I was just explaining that this catched my attention... and I was right, issue is coming from there.

Comment: @Sulthan Also I do know this isn't a leak technically speaking, but it still means some data stays in memory even if I don't want it to.

Comment: If somebody voted to close this question, please explain why.